# ModuleMap path resolution

Tags: xcode, swift

I created my own wrapper around a dylib. I then created a header file to export symbols from this library. I run into the situation where this header is in the wrapper and modulemap can't find it.

```
> MyFramework (project directory)

  > MyFramework.xcconfig

    MODULEMAP_FILE[sdk=macosx*] = $(SRCROOT)/MyFramework/macosx.modulemap


  > macosx.modulemap:

    module MyFramework [system] {
      header "MyFramework.h"     // CAN NOT FIND THE FILE
      export *
    }

  > MyFramwork.h (contains a bunch of declarations)
```

I found examples with absolute paths pointing in the SDK but I really don't want to hard-code the path to my project on my local drive.

I tried prefixing the file name with $(SRCROOT)/MyFramework and other relative options but no luck.

What should I use instead?

Comment: have you tried 'module/module.modulemap' or in your case macosx.modulemap ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [clang module documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-declaration) you find the documentation for Module Maps. Especially there is a `framework` keyword for Mac OS X frameworks. So you should use

```
framework module MyFramework [system] {
  header "MyFramework.h"
  export *
}
```